# Use the same gform twice on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, gravityforms

I'm working in a website that needs to have the same form displayed multiple times on the same page.

The plugin that builds the forms is [Gravity Forms](https://docs.gravityforms.com/).

I have already research on the documentation provided and I couldn't find any action that does the job.

I think I'll need to create a function that store in an array the ID of every single form created and do a comparison for every new form, so then I can probably change the ID of the form element(???).

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by printing the GravityForm inside a `noscript` tag and removing from that when the form is required.

See the example:

```js
var $formContainer = $(".formContainer");
function hide_form($container) {
  $container.slideUp();
  var add_noscript_tag = "<noscript>" + $container[0].innerHTML + "</noscript>";
  $container.empty();
  $container.append(add_noscript_tag);
}
function show_form($container) {
  var remove_noscript_tag = $container[0].innerHTML
    .replace("<noscript>", "")
    .replace("</noscript>", "");
  $container.empty();
  $container.append(remove_noscript_tag);
  $container.slideDown();
}
$("button").click(function() {
  var $FormContainer = $(this).next();
  if ($FormContainer.is(":visible")) {
    hide_form($FormContainer);
  } else {
    var $otherForm = $(".formContainer:visible");
    if ($otherForm.length > 0) {
      hide_form($otherForm);
    }
    show_form($FormContainer);
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.formContainer {
  display: none;
  background: #eee;
}
.formContainer form {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>open form 1</button>
  <div class="formContainer">
    <noscript>
      <form>
        <input type="text" value="Name"/>
        <input type="text" value="Phone"/>
        <input type="text" value="Email"/>
      </form>
    </noscript>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button>open form 2</button>
  <div class="formContainer">
    <noscript>
      <form>
        <input type="text" value="Name"/>
        <input type="text" value="Phone"/>
        <input type="text" value="Email"/>
      </form>
    </noscript>
  </div>
</div>
```